# Wired connection disconnects after a while

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet

I have problem with the Wired Connection on Ubuntu 18.04 which keeps disconnecting after a while.I chaged the Ethernet Cable but it happens again.

**Mainboard Asus Z390 E Gaming**

**sudo lshw -c network**

```
description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: eno2
   version: 10
   serial: 04:92
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:123 memory:a1200000-a121ffff
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) auto lo iface lo inet loopback
```

Please help me to fix this. Thank you !

**UPDATE**
Here is the status of sudo service network-manager status before the Wired connection was working and after it got disconnected.

https://pastebin.com/fpLYyqXp

Comment: is the eth cable male connector damaged on either end of the cable allowing it to come loose?

Comment: I don't see that the cable somewhere is damaged, btw I havent used before this cable its a new.. TYPE CAT5E

Comment: okay just checking, it's always worth looking, you never know. as it stands this problem is very unlikely to be software related. what about the ISP box? it the setup wall telephone socket -> ISP box -> Ubuntu PC or something more convoluted? If you happen to have a windows 10 iso lying around, do you mind installing a dual boot temporarily as a means to confirm that this is or isn't software-related?

Comment: I have already dual boot, checked again on windows is everything ok. I have Huawei Mobile Pro Wifi E5770 and it has only one Ethernet port which is connected to the PC

Comment: I don't understand, you connected your mobile phone to the eth? if you checked on the exact same hardware but with windows and the problem went away then we can indeed assume a software problem, is this a new ubuntu install and the problem  happened right from the get-go or is this an ubuntu you've been using but the problem poped up now?

Comment: No its not a mobile, its a device which works with 4G and has ethernet port. Yes its a new install about two weeks ago. At the beginning it was working fine, but after that it keeps disconnecting.

Comment: i have same problem in Ubuntu 16.04 . i used same wire network on windows and everything was fine . but in ubuntu it will disconnect after a while . did you find any solution ?

Comment: @abasnikzad Hi, open nm-connection-editor via terminal, select wired connection -> edit the selected connection -> general -> Link negotiation -> set to Ignore or (Manual)

Comment: @kannzzmm2 there is no Link negotiation  in general Tab !

Comment: @abasnikzad I made a mistake, it's in the Ethernet Tab...

Comment: @kannzzmm2 Again ! There is no Link negotiation inside Ethernet Tab ,